# OpsHub: Getting error while giving Endpoint details,when migrating to VSonline

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Getting error while giving Endpoint details while migrating to `VSonlineError`:

> Error creating the webProxy specified in the 'System.net/defaultProxy'
>   configuration section.

I am running opshub on win12 64bit os, .net framework also installed and the machine is behind a proxy. Hence I added a new environment variable with the name `"_JAVA_OPTIONS` based on http://opshub.com/main/index.php/ovsomu-proxy.

I added the variables below:

1. `_JAVA_OPTIONS`
2. `-Dhttp.proxyHost=ipaddress -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=username  -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword -Dhttps=false`

Can someone please let me know the workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That proxy setting is just for the installer. You also need to set it for the actual program.

I had the same error as you but fixed it by opening C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\TFSUtility\ovsmu.exe.config and deleting defaultProxy from system.net.